# deleting a marker after confirmation infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Yet another `{"error": "Please use POST request"}` from jsFiddle is thwarting my attempt to delete a google-maps-api-3 marker after getting confirmation from the user. [My jsFiddle code is here](http://jsfiddle.net/PPUVY/1/). You can see the error by first creating one or more markers by clicking on the map, and then right-clicking on one of the markers. Finally, click on the "Delete" button.

The code [borrows heavily from this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396129/).

**EDIT**

3 corrections.

1. As pointed out in a comment, I had not updated the jsFiddle. A corrected version can be found at [/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/PPUVY/5/). The main diff is that the line of code inside the Listener for 'rightclick' is commented out, as it should have been all along.
2. That same correction of commenting out a line of code is done below.
3. I am no longer getting the error "{"error": "Please use POST request"}" unless I make a manual change to the jsfiddle code (such as deleting the commented out line altogether), then Control-Return, and then try to add and delete markers. So that is no longer a problem, I believe. Instead the new problem is that if there are multiple markers and I click on just one of them and request its deletion, instead **all** markers are deleted. So I really need some help to accomplish my goal of deleting markers, one at a time.

The code below

**EDIT**

```
var map
var infowindow;
var markers = [];

function initialize() {

    var NY = new google.maps.LatLng(40.739112, -73.785848);
    map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: NY,
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
        addMarker(event.latLng);
    });
}

function addMarker(location) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);

    var delform = marker.getPosition() + '<br />' + '<form onsubmit="processdel(this,marker); return false" action="#">' + '  <input type="submit" id="delid" value="Delete" />' + '<\/form>';

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: delform,
        size: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function (event) {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);

        // marker.setMap(null); This is the line that was NOT supposed to be in the code.
    });
}

function processdel(form, marker) {

    infowindow.close();
    marker.setMap(null);
    marker = null;
}


initialize();
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you "updated" your jsfiddle. The [code there](http://jsfiddle.net/PPUVY/) is pretty boring.  This is probably what you wanted [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PPUVY/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I am new to jsFiddle and did not know about the requirement to update. Also, as you can see in the edited question, I get new bad results with the updates.

Comment: It doesn't get deleted. You are just refreshing the page by the use of the form submit. So your map loads again without any markers.

Comment: @MrUpsidown that is a surprise, but you may be right. Anyhow, I think I may have found an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521766/), and it includes its own jsFiddle demo. Apparently I must build a `markers` object that contains all the markers. Oh, btw, I looked at your edit of the question and I could only see what looked like formatting changes that were not really important. Was there anything substantive that you added?

Comment: Nope. I would never change anything in your code. That's part of your question. I only indented it correctly. You are correct about the markers "object" which actually is an array, but you did that already. I will add an answer in a sec to explain further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few *rules* to achieve what you want.

1. Create only one instance of the infowindow object and use `setContent()` method to modify its content.
2. Use the `domready` event of the infowindow to bind any action to an element within the infowindow.
3. Add an Id to each marker so that you are able to identify each one separately. I used a simple counter in the below example. Increment it each time you create a marker.

First create the infowindow instance and a counter:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var counter = 0;
```

Then create each marker with a specific id and use that id on the infowindow button:

```
function addMarker(location) {

    counter++;

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
        id: counter
    });

    markers.push(marker);

    var deleteButton = '<button id="deleteButton" data-id="' + counter + '">Delete</button>';

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function () {
        infowindow.setContent(deleteButton);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

Then you need to listen to the `domready` event of the infowindow, call your delete function with the marker id that you get from the button, and finally loop through your markers array to delete the appropriate marker.

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/Sgswc/)</kbd>

Comment: I edited your JSFiddle, [see this one](http://jsfiddle.net/Sgswc/3/) to use `var markers = {}` instead of `[]` (as did @Fatih). I am not sure if that is necessary for the change in `function deleteMarker(markerId)`, but the change eliminates the need for a forloop lookup. Will such a change be efficient for most apps, and work? One question about your requirement for only one infowindow. Can I have another independent infowindow  for users to provide text for their button, named something else? That is, is the limit of one infowindow particular to the deletes?

Comment: I'm stuck on the part of listening to the `domready` event. I think that is because I do not use jQuery, so this code from fiddle does not work for me: `google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function () {
        
        $("#deleteButton").click(function() {

            deleteMarker($(this).data('id'));
        });
    });
}` Can you help with this?

Comment: Ok, I got that question about eschewing jQuery answered with another question, but now it appears that the issue of this approach allowing only one global infowindow is a BIG problem for me. Is there another design which uses different infowindows for deletes  relative to marker creation?

Comment: `markers` was an array and you turned it into an object. That doesn't change anything regarding the loop thing. What changes is that you used the counter as the array key / object property which actually is more clever than what I did at first (no need for the loop). Now what is the BIG problem you are talking about?