# Coding without jQuery

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416189) says "listen to the domready event of the infowindow" and provides a JSFiddle.com solution which includes the following code. How can I code this without the `$`s which I assume are jQuery?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function () {
        $("#deleteButton").click(function() {
            deleteMarker($(this).data('id'));
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this :

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function () {
    var button = document.getElementById('deleteButton');
    var id = parseInt(button.getAttribute('data-id'));  
    button.onclick = function() {
        deleteMarker(id);
    };
});
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/BAv48/**

It is very important to ensure `id` is of type number (by using `parseInt`) since the `id` in the `markers` array is of type number and `deleteMarker` compares with `if (markers[i].id === markerId) { .. }`.

Comment: Your answer worked best because it made it clear to me that `button.onclick` was a distinct action. I need that and hope to use it correctly because I want to not just remove the pin from the map, but also remove it from the datastore.

Answer (score 0):

Use [***document.getElementById***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) to get the element, then use [***addEventListener***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) to setup the click event listener. For the `.data` call use [***getAttribute***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute)

```
document.getElementById("deleteButton").addEventListener("click",function(){
   deleteMarker(this.getAttribute("data-id"));
});
```

Note for IE < 9 use [attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of `addEventListener`

Comment: This does not work for me when I substitute it into the JSFiddle.com code. I get the infowindow to open, but clicking the delete button no longer does anything.