# text input to a global infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, domready

[This question extends an answer here that uses `domready`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416189/). The extension is an attempt to include a second infowindow with a slightly different name: `inwindow` vs `infowindow`. The first question is, given the answerer's first "rule" -- "Create only one instance of the infowindow object and use setContent() method to modify its content." -- can there **be** a second infowindow object?

If so, then what is wrong with my attempt at creating `inwindow` as shown below? `inwindow` appears when the map is clicked, but clicking its "Submit" button does not seem to do anything.

[A working JSFiddle.com version](http://jsfiddle.net/3qU88/3/) is here (at least it shows a map).

Some global vars and objects are next.

```
var map
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var inwindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var markers = [];
var counter = 0;
```

`initialize()` is excerpted next.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {

    addMarker(event.latLng);
    });

google.maps.event.addListener(inwindow, 'domready', function () {
    var button = document.getElementById('inputButton');
    var input = document.getElementById('nameinput').value;
    button.onsubmit = function() {
    marker.title = input;
    inwindow.close();
    };
    });
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function () {
    var button = document.getElementById('deleteButton');
    var id = parseInt(button.getAttribute('data-id'));  
    button.onclick = function() {
    deleteMarker(id);
    };
    });
}

function addMarker(location) {

    counter++;

    var inputForm = 'Name:  <input type="text" id="nameinput" size="31" maxlength="31" tabindex="1"/>' + '<input type="button" id="inputButton" value="Submit">';

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: location,
map: map,
id: counter
});
inwindow.setContent(inputForm);
inwindow.open(map, marker);

markers.push(marker);

var deleteButton = '<button id="deleteButton" data-id="' + counter + '">Delete</button>';

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function () {
    infowindow.setContent(deleteButton);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}

function deleteMarker(markerId) {
    for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
    if (markers[i].id === markerId) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: `can there be a second infowindow object?` Using the Google Maps API v3 there can be as many InfoWindows as you want.  This version of the API removed the hard limitation of only one that was built into v2 of the API.

Comment: [fixed jsfiddle that at least shows a map](http://jsfiddle.net/3qU88/3/) (was getting a javascript error `google is undefined`, added the API as an external resource, changed the "Frameworks and Extensions setting to `no wrap in <head>`, added an onload event to call initialize on the window load event).

Comment: <rant> Why in the world would `var map = null;` be required instead of `var map;`? And why can't I just make that change to my JSFiddle.net version, click `Run`  and see a map? On the other hand why is it that if in YOUR JSFiddle.net, if I change `var map = null;` to `var map;` and click `Run`, does the map still show? Cussword! <rant off> And that's not even the main problem I am trying to solve, namely getting an input to work in the maps environment.

Comment: I just noticed that you said above that jsfiddle was getting a javascript error. Where to you see errors in jsfiddle? I don't think I have seen one.

Comment: In the javascript console of your browser (I usually use Chrome, unless it is a browser specific problem).  BTW - the `var map=null;` is not required, just habit, you were missing a semi-colon at the end of the line, when I fixed that I added the `=null;`.

Comment: I understand it isn't the problem you are trying do solve, but a working jsfiddle will help others to help you.  I did't have time to look at answering your question, but did have time to fix the fiddle to make it useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have as many infowindows as you want. The *rules* I gave you [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24430067/1238965) were more like hints (hence the italic font). You can always adapt it to your needs.

Now you have a few issues in your code:

1. `onsubmit` event is triggered when the submit button in a form is clicked. The action should be on the form, not on the button. But you don't have a form here. You can use `onclick` event instead (like for the delete button).
2. You get the input value when the infowindow is ready (`domready`) not after the user has filled the field. Therefore it will always be empty.
3. You set `marker.title = xxx` but `marker` is not available here, plus, you should use the `setTitle()` method to change a marker title.
4. Why didn't you use the same technique that I (and you) used for the delete button action? (using the Id, etc.) I suggest that you try to understand what happens there and adapt it to the part where you set the marker title.

If you are still stuck, let me know and I will explain further!

**Edit:**

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/ZW79H/)</kbd>

Note that there is no tabindex defined on the inputs and buttons, and that I used `.focus()` to set the focus on the input or button when the infowindow opens.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I had 2 problems which are now overcome with your answer. First I did not understand the purpose of domready and what triggered it. I also did not know how to include a "form" without the "<form>" tag. I ended up doing the following. `var inputForm = 'Name:  <input type="text" id="nameinput" ' + '<input type="hidden" id="pinId" value="' + counter + '">' + '<button id="inputButton">Submit</button>';` which also includes the **hidden** pinId. That was the last piece that was missing.

Comment: You don't really need the hidden field. You can add a data-*xxx* attribute to any HTML element (like I did on the delete button). Just a hint.

Comment: Yes, [here I was reminded of that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499785/), but I am seeing a problem with an extra TAB index using this method. When you "hid" in the delete button, there was only one TAB, the button. But it seems if I have a more substantial pseudo "form", I get an extra TAB. Have you ever encountered that problem? Prior to your suggested global infowindow, I had always used real forms and had no such problem.

Comment: What problem? Using one input field and a button, I don't see any tabulation issue. I will put a jsfiddle in my answer in a sec.

Comment: Yes your jsfiddle is very helpful. It does not work the way I want and I think I do need another infowindow with `domready` because I only want the user to edit an existing marker after first deleting it, and then reentering it to make such actions a little harder. So no `addListener` that associates a **marker** and a (left) click. But when I only eliminate your such `addListener`, I can not delete any marker, so I am working to rectify that problem. FYI, I want altering an existing marker to be a little difficult to make it a little harder for a bad-doer to destroy several markers on a map.