# hidden <input> not in a <form> is included in "tab" sequence

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

In google maps v3 I am using an infowindow. I am using the following variable as the content of the infowindow (because I don't know how to use a  in this situation).

```
var inputForm = 'Name:  <input type="text" id="nameinput" size="31" maxlength="31" tabindex="1" />' + '<input type="hidden" id="pinId" value="' + counter + '" />' + '<button id="inputButton">Submit</button>';
```

The problem is that in the infowindow bubble the "hidden" input requires an extra Tab for the user. I have read answers in SO that suggest using `<div` with `display: none` but I am not aware of using a `<div` in a variable like my `inputForm`.

How can I remove the unnecessary Tab?

EDIT code:

To test this code, click somewhere and a marker with an infowindow appears. Click inside the bubble and then use Tab to see it stops between the text field and the Submit button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html { height: 100% }
        body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
        #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var inwindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var markers = [];
        var counter = 0;

        function initialize() {

        var NY = new google.maps.LatLng(40.739112, -73.785848);
        map = new google.maps.Map(
            document.getElementById('map-canvas'), { center: NY, zoom: 16, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP });

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
            addMarker(event.latLng);
            });

        google.maps.event.addListener(inwindow, 'domready', function () {
            var button = document.getElementById('inputButton');
            button.onclick = function() {
            var input = document.getElementById('nameinput').value;
            var id = parseInt(document.getElementById('pinId').value);
            titleMarker(id, input);
            inwindow.close();
            };
            });


        function addMarker(location) {

            counter++;

            var inputForm = 'Name:  ' + '<input type="text" id="nameinput" size="31" maxlength="31" tabindex="1" />' + '<input type="hidden" id="pinId" value="' + counter + '" tabindex="-1" />' + '<button id="inputButton">Submit</button>';

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: location,
map: map,
draggable: true,
id: counter
});
inwindow.setContent(inputForm);
inwindow.open(map, marker);

markers.push(marker);

}

function titleMarker(markerId, markerTitle) {
    for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
    if (markers[i].id === markerId) {
        markers[i].setTitle(markerTitle);
    }
    }
}



google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the element to be tabbed to, set the tabindex to `-1`, which removes the element from the tabindex

```
var inputForm = 'Name:  ' +
  '<input type="text" id="nameinput" size="31" maxlength="31" tabindex="1" />' + 
  '<input type="hidden" id="pinId" value="' + counter + '" tabindex="-1" />' + 
  '<button id="inputButton">Submit</button>';
```

Comment: I wasn't aware `type="hidden"` elements could be tabbed to in the first place.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - Neither was I, I think older IE would keep hidden elements in the tab order, but the OP is claiming that this is what happens in Google Maps, and the way to remove an element from the tab order is to set the tabindex to a negative value.

Comment: Something crazy is going on. When I put your answer into JSFiddle I don't get the tab with or without your addition of a -1 tab index. But then your answer changes nothing on my Chrome on Mac as a standalone html file. I'll add the complete test code to the question to see if it's something else like the header that is causing a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a hidden input?  Why not just store the value as a data attribute on the input itself?

```
var inputForm = 'Name:  ' + 
'<input type="text" id="nameinput" size="31" maxlength="31" tabindex="1" data-pinid="'+ counter +'" />' + 
'<button id="inputButton">Submit</button>';
```

Then you could retrieve it like:

```
var input = document.getElementById('nameinput').value;
var id = parseInt(input.getAttribute('data-pinid'));
```

Comment: That's a great idea, but when I enter your definition in to my code, I still get an extra Tab. What am I doing wrong? (I must admit I am having a hard time getting MY code above to run. I keep getting the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input ")