# Having some problems with InfoWindows. Not really sure how to approach it

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to make an edit system for the markers' Infowindow contents. I need to get the clicked marker's id value, but i am not sure how to get it.

I have tried to get the value trough a button in the content of the infowindow
with this code
`infowindow.setContent( "<div id='infowindow'>"+ addDescription +"</div>"+"<div id='iddiv'>Id: "+addId+"</div>"+"<button onclick='sendToEdit'>edit</button>");` but I guess that it didn't work. The result is an undefined value.

this is the sendToEdit() function

```
function sendToEdit()
{
  var addIdStr = JSON.stringify(addId);
  $.ajax({
    url: "edit.php",
    method: "post",
    data: {addId:addIdStr},
    success: function(res)
    {
      console.log("success")
    }
  });
  window.open("edit.php");
}
```

```
function AddMarker(addDescription,addId)
  {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
      position: {lat: arr[0], lng:arr[1]},
      map: map,
      title: 'Click to zoom',
      id: addId,
    });
    markers.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
        infowindow.close(); // Close previously opened infowindow
        infowindow.setContent( "<div id='infowindow'>"+ addDescription +"</div>"+"<div id='iddiv'>Id: "+addId+"</div>"+"<button onclick='sendToEdit()'>edit</button>");
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [deleting a marker after confirmation infowindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416189/deleting-a-marker-after-confirmation-infowindow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To edit a specific info window for a specific marker you'll need to send that marker's own id.

```
"<button onclick='sendToEdit(" + marker.id + ")'>edit</button>"
```

Then you can get this id in your `sendToEdit` function:

```
function sendToEdit(markerId)
{
  var addIdStr = JSON.stringify(markerId);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad to hear! Happy to have been of help :)